# Batch files with dynamic arguments

Tags: file, batch-file, arguments

I need some help in writing a batch file; it launches another application which requires dynamic arguments.

I tried the following but the system cannot find the path specified:

```
 start nw.exe -config "C:\NWconfig\i1.txt" -v -t > i1.rez
```

Any help/advice will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the content of "C:\NWconfig\i1.txt" ? You can just read it , set the content to a variable and pass the new variable to nw.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=," %%G IN ("C:\NWconfig\i1.txt") DO SET PARAM=%%G
start nw.exe -config %PARAM% -v -t > i1.rez
```

This will read i1.txt content and will pass it to nw.exe as argument.